Loading Web Feature Service (WFS) takes too long in QGIS
I am trying to load WFS (URL for Cadastral data of a federal state in Germany) in QGIS LTR but it is extremely time-consuming. I know, it is a big dataset.
Whenever I try to load the layer, it shows partly on the map canvas. When I zoom in then again it loads features in the map canvas. So, I need to zoom in to load all the features in the state. It takes hours of work which is boring.
Is there any other solution to load this data quickly?


See: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/210723/qgis-rendering-performance-bottleneck and https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/325862/slow-loading-of-qgis-project

Do you have to load all of it? Can you set a scale range so it doesnt render at small scales? Or are there WMS services from the same provider you can use?

use curl and paging

Can you please show the Rendering tab of your layer properties? Have you tried to unselect Simplify Geometry? Do not forget to select the 'Only request features overlapping the view extent' when importing your WFS. Also, you can investigate the temporal issue via View > Panels > Debugging/Development Tools under Category: Map Render. There I can see that rendering features takes the longest. So you can: (1) Filter Legend by Map Content (2) Settings > Options > Rendering (3) Create Spatial Index.

Most probably the data shows only partly when zoomed out because the service provider has limited the number of features which can be downloaded with one request. Read about paging from https://docs.ogc.org/is/09-025r2/09-025r2.html. By the same you will learn how to fetch all the data page by page with manually written requests. Or you can use ogr2ogr with the WFS driver that supports paging https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/wfs.html.

This service has come up in quite a few questions.  like https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/296416/downloading-wfs-data-using-qgis and https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/431972/sql-query-to-limit-loaded-feature-from-wfs-layer-to-the-extent-of-a-feature-in-a  it has a huge number of features and you will have to download in parts using paging
